# Show that X is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have a basis for $X$, a subspace of $P^2(\mathbb R)$, which is {$x^2-4/3,x$}.

I need to show that $X$ is indeed a basis. I understand that I need to prove that the elements are linear independent and span $P^2$ and I can do this if I set up my matrix correctly. But the matrix I have at the moment seems wrong and I'm a bit stuck:

$$
\begin{matrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\ 
        -4/3 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

Shouldn't my matrix be 3x3 before I add the last column for $(0,0,0)$ or $(x,y,z)$ depending on whether I'm testing for linear independence or span? Bit confused...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P^2(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $3$, there is no way for that set being a basis for it. You meant "(...) linearly independent and span $X$ (...)"

Well, that set span $X$ by definition, and it is linearly independent 'cause
$$a(x^2-4/3) + bx = 0 = 0x^2+0x+0$$
implies
$$a=b=0.$$

---

Answering your question: the matrix shouldn't have $3\times 3$. It only needs to have $2$ linearly independent lines or columns (and it has!)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why can you just say that the set spans X by definition?

Comment: You said you have "a basis for $X$"..

Comment: Yeah, I need to prove it's a basis though

Comment: Right. What is the set $X$? (I assume that $X=span\{x^2-4/3, x\}$)

Comment: $X$ = $\{p \in P_2(\mathbb{R}): p'(-1)-2 \int_0^1 p(x) dx = 0\}$. I then found the basis of X to be {$x^2-4/3,x$} and I need to prove this.

Comment: Ok so, if your calculations are correct, you only have to check that $x^2-4/3\in X$ and $x\in X$. The proof that both are linearly independent is in my answer.